# Eliminar filas de varias tablas al mismo tiempo con MySQL

Tags: mysql

estoy intentando eliminar varias filas de varias tablas al mismo tiempo utilizando esta sentencia en mysql

```
DELETE fhi, ave, car, pen FROM fhi INNER JOIN ave INNER JOIN car INNER JOIN pen
                WHERE fhi.id = 1
                AND fhi.id2 = 4
                AND ave.id = 1
                AND ave.id2 = 4
                AND car.id = 1
                AND car.id2 = 4
                AND pen.id= 4;
```

Al insertar esta sentencia no me da error pero no elimina nada, sale esto:  0 filas afectadas. (La consulta tardó 0,0000 segundos.). Estoy utilizando phpMyAdmin 4.7.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La sentencia no genera Resultado porque los join no se han incializado por asi decirlo.

Debes de relacionarlos utilizando (ON)
deberia de quedar asi.

DELETE fhi,ave,car,pen

FROM fhi

INNER JOIN ave ON ave.id = 1 AND ave.id2 = 4

INNER JOIN car ON car.id = 1 AND car.id2 = 4

INNER JOIN pen ON pen.id = 4

WHERE

fhi.id = 1 AND fhi.id2 = 4;

Comment: al hacerlo asi se borran las filas de las 4 tablas?

Comment: asi es se borraría filas de las cuatro tablas.lo he probado y funciona correctamente.